# How do I get Doxygen to document a class defined in a C++ file?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I know classes should be defined in hpp files. Company convention requires me to keep this particular class in a cpp file.

Doxygen is parsing the cpp file in question and documenting a few #defines in it, but totally skipping over the class. How do I get Doxygen to see it? Can I put something in the doxyfile or in the file itself?

Comment: Have you documented the cpp-file with `// @file`?

Comment: Can you show us how you have documented the class in the .cpp file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Doxygen documentation located here: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#config_build

I found these two options which should be of help:

EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES
If the EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES tag is set to YES classes (and structs) defined locally in source files will be included in the documentation. If set to NO only classes defined in header files are included. Does not have any effect for Java sources.

EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES
If this flag is set to YES, the members of anonymous namespaces will be extracted and appear in the documentation as a namespace called 'anonymous_namespace{file}', where file will be replaced with the base name of the file that contains the anonymous namespace. By default anonymous namespace are hidden.